how to prove that the sheaf of discontinuous functions of any sheaf over a topological space is a soft sheaf?
I am studying "Differential analysis on complex manifolds" by R.O. Wells. In page number 55 of the book, they are saying that the sheaf of discontinuous functions of any sheaf over a topological space is a soft sheaf. But how to prove this statement?

Welcome to the site. I normally hear of "soft" in the context of compactly supported cohomology and locally compact Hausdorff spaces, but you want something more general. But any rate, these sheaves enjoy excellent lifting properties. They are flabby, ou peut-etre flasque, easily; if $s\in\mathscr{F}(V)$ i.e. $s:V\to\Bbb R$ is just some function then we may lift $s$ to a global section $t:X\to\Bbb R$ just via $t(x):=\begin{cases}0&x\notin V\\s(x)&x\in V\end{cases}$ and since we don't care about continuity or anything like that, this is possible; $\mathscr{F}(X)\to\mathscr{F}(V)$ is always surjective.
It would be good to add more context to future questions, but this one (I think!) is simple enough.

yeah i want more general. They didn't use any such conditions(u can see in the mentioned book). But thanks for the comment, i got a small hints(whatever liftings u gave, it can be modified as for the discontinuous sections , one more condition is there), hopefully it will work. Thanks
